# Clean solution: populate <ul> via Embedded Code or Code Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Suppose I have to populate an unordered list with data from a `Dictionary` in a project not using MVC. I'm sure ASP.Net lovers will tell me to populate everything from code-behind.
But... should I?

Via embedded code:

```
<ul>
<% foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in MyDictonary) { %>
    <li><%= item.Key %>: <strong><%= item.Value %></strong></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

I agree it is not a lot clean, but the alternative is a lot worse as I got to write HTML markup directly from my method:

```
public void writeMyDictionary() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<ul>");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in MyDictonary) {
        sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}: <strong>{1}</strong></li>", item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    sb.Append("</ul>");
    MyControl.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

So, why should I use code-behind to populate all my controls?

Comment: And where would I write my `<li>` tags, configure css classes, ids, and its HTML content?

Comment: The Repeater control is pretty good for that stuff..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this use case, there is no particular value to doing it in code behind.

I would rather use the markup version instead of the code behind, as you have posted them, but chances are I would simply go with data binding on a [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx), as it would be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using repeater controls http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Which is less surprising for someone maintaining this (e.g. if they want to change the markup)?

Code-behind is probably not the first place they would look.